# Ubuntu unity webapps not working in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: unity, webapps, gmail, amazon

I installed livemail and gmail in Ubuntu 14.10 but I get a blank screen. Someone said that there is an update needed about something called Unity-Schema something. 
Anybody knows a work around or the cause of the problem?

Comment: same here on 14.04 and 14.10

Comment: No actually it works on 14.04 for me, or better say worked. Maybe since I last stopped using 14.04 a few days ago there has been an update such as an ubuntu browser update that might have caused the problem. Maybe I can help you with the 14.04 issue.

Comment: it seems the same issue, but let's try to solve the 14.04 first...

Comment: Did you change graphic drivers? For a while they did not work while I was changing from the open source xorg driver to the proprietary ati radeon driver. They worked well after the reboot. They worked out of the box anyway without installing any proprietary driver for me. So I think you might have done something that interferes with them working properly. You can reset unity, there are some commands for that. I am now using 14.04 and they work great even after the updates.

Comment: And did you install them using the software centre?

Comment: installed with synaptics. Regarding graphics, I'm using intel open xorg driver.

Comment: But I have a workaround. Completely uninstall amazon or webappscommon as it is called if I remember correctly. If you have chromium installed simply go to the chrome webstore and add facebook or youtube or outlook. After that go to apps in your chromium and right click say facebook and add it as an application or to the desktop. If a page you want is not found at the chrome webstore, you can open that page and click the settings on the far right, click tools and then click create application shortcuts.

Comment: this workaround adds chromium app, not the web browser app. And I don't want to use chromium.

Comment: We have to wait for an update to ubuntu unity-schemas, until that we can't do anything. For you I would suggest removing completely all webapps and the ubuntu browser as well from the synaptic. The n re-install. This should work if you are using 14.04. For 14.10 there should be an update but there hasn't been any at all until now.

Comment: @ErvinDine is there a bug that we can subscribe to?

Comment: Yes there is. Somebody filed a bug about it here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-webapps-livemail/+bug/1377942. Too bad I was looking forward to test the new web-apps. Will wait for a fix before I upgrade to 14.10.